# no suitable constructor found for GameDetails(int,int) constructor GameDetails.GameDetails() is not applicable

Tags: java

Hello I'm still new to Netbeans and completly new to StackoverFlow and coding in General and I need to finish the creation of a SpaceInvaders game and I've reached astopping point. For my no Arg-Constructor I've followed the methods I've used in the previous weeks but to no avail. I understand most who view this might find it patheticly easy, but I appricate any help regardless.

```
package model;

import dao.GameDetailsDAO;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * <p>
 * The details for one game, including the user playing, the game settings the scoring (shots fired, ships destroyed,
 * score and previous high score)
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Company: TAFE SA</p>
 *
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class GameDetails implements Serializable {

    //constants
    public static final int POINTS_GAINED_FOR_SHIP_DESTROYED = 100;
    public static final int POINTS_LOST_FOR_WASTED_SHOT = 50;

    //instance variables set at object creation time
    private UserDetails userDetails;
    private GameSettings gameSettings;

    //instance variables NOT set at object creation time but updated through setters as game is played.

    private int highScore;
    private int score;
    private int shipsDestroyed;
    private int shotsFired;
    private boolean newHighScore; //Indicates wether the highScore is a new one

    //only 2 constructors required
    /**
     * UserDetails
     *
     *
     * 
     */
    //no args constructor
       public GameDetails(){
        this(POINTS_GAINED_FOR_SHIP_DESTROYED , POINTS_LOST_FOR_WASTED_SHOT, new UserDetails(), new GameSettings());
    }



    //all args constructor
    public GameDetails(UserDetails userDetails, GameSettings gameSettings, int highScore, int score, int shipsDestroyed, int shotsFired, boolean newHighScore) throws Exception {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
        this.gameSettings = gameSettings;
        this.highScore = highScore;
        this.score = score;
        this.shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed;
        this.shotsFired = shotsFired;
        this.newHighScore = newHighScore;


        resetTheScoringDetails();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is javascript

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: Your constructor class have different parameters

Comment: Somewhere, in code you haven't shown, you did `new GameDetails(i, j)` (where `i` and `j` are some integers.  Your `GameDetails` class---the part you've shown, at least---doesn't appear to have a constructor that takes two integer args. If you want to construct a `GameDetails` from two integers, you have to write a constructor with the exact signature: `public GameDetails(int i1, int i2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no suitable constructor found for GameDetails(int,int) constructor GameDetails.GameDetails() is not applicable

You don't have a constuctor for `GameDetails` that takes exactly 2 `int` parameters.

What you have are:

```
public GameDetails()
public GameDetails(UserDetails, GameSettings, int, int, int, int, boolean)
```

You either need to write a new constructor - `public GameDetails(int, int)` - or add/remove parameters to match one of your existing constructor signatures.